# Using fgets + dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, fgets, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a homework problem that I need help with. I need to implement a function `char *getStrFromFile(FILE*);`. I just simply don't understand it. I have attempted to figure out the question.

> This function safely reads a complete line of unknown length from the
>   open file pointed to by fpin. It returns a line that is at most CHUNKSZ-1
>   characters longer than the minimum needed to hold the line.
>   It initially allocates an array of DEFLEN characters to hold the string,
>   and if this space is inadequate to hold the string, it will iteratively
>   create a new string that is CHUNKSZ larger, copy the old string to it
>   release the old string, and then read in more characters from the file,
>   and continue this until the entire line of arbitrary length can be returned.
>
> RETURNS: NULL if no characters are left in fpin, otherwise:
>   pointer to allocated array at most CHUNKSZ-1 characters longer than
>   miminum necessary to hold an arbitrarily long line from file fpin

```
 int main(int nargs, char *args[])
 {
    FILE *fpin;
    char *getStrFromFile(FILE*);
    if (nargs != 2)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s <file>\n", args[0]);
       exit(1);
    }
    fpin = fopen(args[1], "r");
    while(1)
    {
       char *ln;
       ln = getStrFromFile(fpin);
       if (!ln)
          break;
       printf("%s", ln);
       free(ln);
    }
    fclose(fpin);
    return(0);
 }
```

That is the main method I have to use. Here is what I know so far.

```
char *getStrFromFile(FILE *fpin)
{
  char string[DEFLEN];
  if(fgets(string, CHUNKSZ, fpin) != NULL) {
    int l = lstr(string);
    if(string[l-1] = '\n') {
      return string;
    } else {
      int size = 1;
      int end = 0;
      while (string[l-1] != '\n') {
        size += CHUNSZ;
        char *s2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+size);
        for(i = 0+end; i < lstr(string); i++) {
          s2[i] = string[i];
        }
        end += lstr(string);
        fgets(string, size + end, fpin);
        return s2;
```

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘know ro far’? You show us a bit of truncated source code.

Comment: This code doesn't work. I need to use fgets iteratively. CHUNSZ and DEFLEN are both cpp macros defined as 1.

Comment: what does `lstr()` return? Is it synonymous with `strlen()` or does it also include the extra char space for the string null-terminator? If it mimics `strlen()` there are several UB-conditions immediately apparent if CHUNKSZ and DEFLEN are defined as 1.

Comment: Also, you didn't really answer Johnny. He asked what it was you didn't understand and you replied "The code doesn't work." The original question suggested you didn't understand *the question*, but your response indicates you understand the question, but *not your code.* So please clarify: **Is it the question or your own code you don't understand?**

Answer (score 5):

This is not correct.

```
if(string[l-1] = '\n')
```

it must be

```
if(string[l-1] == '\n')
```